# Troubles to show the browser using puppeteer from WSL2

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have troubles when i try to execute my script using puppeteer with the "headless" option set up in false to show the browser

Im Working with WSL2, here is my script

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    console.log('Start Scraping...');

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); <-- Here's the problem

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js');

    await browser.close();

    console.log('End Scraping...');

})()
```

This is the output when i try to run it

```
Start Scraping...
(node:3057) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[3068:3068:0429/043013.248542:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1393)] Unable to open X display.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/nilsonkr/courses/nodejs/foundaments/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:194:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/nilsonkr/courses/nodejs/foundaments/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:185:79)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3057) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3057) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

When i set that value to true or just don't write it , it works, but i am still wondering what is the reason and how can i fix it ? to show the browser

i have already tried adding these flags but it didn't work either

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
```